# GNOME shows activities overview when mouse hover dash

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, activities-overview

I got this weird bug recently: When mouse-hovering the dash panel, the activities overview shows up. Why is that? (I'm using "dash to panel" extension).

I'm using Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Activities* getting activated by mouse hover at the top-left corner is in fact a default GNOME shell behaviour. But in Ubuntu 17.10 it's patched not to do so.

I reckon by installing *Dash to Panel* (or some other extension(s)/package(s)) you have broken the patch somehow.

You may use a [GNOME shell extension](https://askubuntu.com/questions/75530/how-do-i-install-and-manage-gnome-shell-extensions) called [No Topleft Hot Corner](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/118/no-topleft-hot-corner/) to disable this hot corner feature.

Comment: I am coming from Ubuntu 16.04 and I _liked_ that feature. How do I re-enable it?

Comment: @pomsky The setting is now exposed in Gnome Tweaks, so can be set there, as user3526273 indicatedor using dconf editor, or using a gsettings command. Better approach than installing another extension. -> sorry, I see I am messing with an older question.

Comment: @vanadium Agreed! Using Tweaks is certainly a better approach.

Comment: @AutonomousApps If you're still interested, you may refer to this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1070621/how-do-i-show-running-windows-without-clicking-the-activities-button-but-only

Answer (score 7):

Use GNOME Tweaks to turn off Activities Overview Hot Corner. 
If Tweaks is not installed, type in bash:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then open Tweaks -> Top Bar -> turn off Activities Overview Hot Corner.

Comment: `sudo apt install tweak` seems to be a wrong command...