# Activities corner keeps "re-enabling" itself

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, gnome-tweak-tool, activities-overview

In Ubuntu 18.04, using Gnome Tweak tool there's a way to disable the Activities hot corner. I have a multi-monitor setup, so having this feature on is extremely annoying. Anyway... After a couple of minutes (sometimes just seconds) the corner seems to re-enable itself. I check on the setting on Gnome Tweak and it's indeed disable. Here's a gif of the situation:

[image]

It seems that the problem happens after gnome-shell is restarted. Seems like this might be a bug, which if confirmed I will report it.

Any ideas on how can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Try to disable it forcefully using an extension (see this: https://askubuntu.com/q/984705/480481).

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to mention that I have used a couple of extension and I still get the same behavior

Comment: May it have connection with this message? https://imgur.com/a/yjyrukk

Comment: I've got this behaviour as well. Very strange. Seems to re-activate every few hours

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the [Dash to Panel](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1160/dash-to-panel/) extension also leaves this setting permanently enabled. If you are using this, you will have to pull a commit this is AFTER [May 10th, 2019](https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/407), or it will be broken. As of today, there has not been a release since March, so you'll have to build master yourself.

---

If this is happening to anyone who isn't using that extension, here is another solution: simply add a job to `crontab` to reset it every 5 minutes.

```
 */5 * * * * gsettings set org.gnome.shell enable-hot-corners false
```

Despite the value never actually being true, this will still cause the gnome shell to refresh, and remember your settings.

Comment: The DashToPanel bug has been reported fixed in May *2018*, not 2019! It seems that the bug reappeared. I opened a new ticket for this: https://github.com/home-sweet-gnome/dash-to-panel/issues/753

Comment: You missed the `user` in the `cron` line, and `gsettings` will need some env to execute, [see this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/742870/background-not-changing-using-gsettings-from-cron)