# How do I show running windows without clicking the "Activities" button but only hovering over it?

Tags: window, gnome-shell, activities-overview

I'm from Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and I just installed Ubuntu 18.04 which contains GNOME by default, but there are a lot less preferences.

I want to open the selection of windows (as if we clicked on the 3 points or "Activities" button) but only when my mouse is in the (top-left) corner of my screen.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First install *(GNOME) Tweaks* by running

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Then launch Tweaks and enable the "**Activities Overview Hot Corner**" option under "*Top Bar*".

[image]

Comment: @J-Jamet I made a few changes in your question to make it applicable to a standard Ubuntu 18.04 installation. In a standard installation there is no "3 dots" button but one "Activities" (or its translation) button. You're most probably using an Arc-like GNOME shell theme which changes the Activities button to a 3 dots one.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet to have a standard gnome session in Ubuntu 18.04 will be to install gnome-session. You can do this from the terminal with the command

```
sudo apt install gnome-session
```

Now restart your computer. When you get to the log-in screen, click the cog icon and select "Gnome on xorg". Then provide your password and press  to log in. You will now be in a standard gnome session, just like the developers of gnome intended. Among others, you will now be able to open the windows overview by moving your cursor in the top left corner.